# Get weapon ID from API (Laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, json, api, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on a Halo 5 API. And I am collecting weapon kills for each player in Arena.

For example, to get total Kills for my Magnum, this is what I do:

```
 public function getPlayerArenaArray($playerArenaStats) {
      $array = [];
      $array['MagnumKills'] = $playerArenaStats->Results[0]->Result->ArenaStats->WeaponStats[0]->TotalKills;

      return $array;
 }
```

And this is the output:

[image: Halo Output]

The problem with this is each players weapon order is different.
So for example if I output this, I get an array of weapons used for that player (in this case me):

```
$ex = $array['MagnumKills'] = $playerArenaStats->Results[0]->Result->ArenaStats->WeaponStats;
dd($ex);
```

And this is the output:

```
array:53 [▼
  0 => {#1576 ▼
    +"WeaponId": {#1577 ▼
      +"StockId": 4096745987.0
      +"Attachments": []
    }
    +"TotalShotsFired": 46355
    +"TotalShotsLanded": 21245
    +"TotalHeadshots": 2212
    +"TotalKills": 2762
    +"TotalDamageDealt": 393650.91875947
    +"TotalPossessionTime": "P1DT1H36M25.5502S"
  }
  1 => {#1578 ▶}
  2 => {#1580 ▶}
  3 => {#1582 ▶}
  4 => {#1584 ▶}
  5 => {#1586 ▶}
  6 => {#1588 ▶}
  7 => {#1590 ▶}
  8 => {#1592 ▶}
  9 => {#1594 ▶}
  10 => {#1596 ▶}

...... and so on
```

For a other player, array[0] will contain a different weapon
And so if I do this in my blade:

```
 <td style="width: 25%;">
            <img src="{{ json_decode($FlagnumImage) }}" class="img-responsive" style=" width: 50%; height: auto;">  <!-- weapon image -->
        </td>
        <td>{{ json_decode($Flagnum) }}</td>        <!-- weapon name -->
        <td>{{ json_decode($MagnumKills) }}</td>    <!-- weapon kills -->
```

For another player, $MagnumKills will mean a different weapon, but it will be under Magnum still.

I hope you guys understand, I need to somehow attach the weapon name and image in the table  to the right weapon kills.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Laravel Collection helper class.

```
collect($array)->pluck('WeaponId.StockId');
```

Comment: ya, it gave me an array of ALL weapon IDs. Iam going to try to assign them now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `keyBy` collection's method?
Your function will look like that:

```
public function getPlayerArenaArray($playerArenaStats) {
    return collect($playerArenaStats->Results[0]->Result->ArenaStats->WeaponStats)->keyBy(
        function($stats) {
            return $stats['WeaponId']['StockId'];
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Use the data returned by my function this way (Let's assume it's assigned to the `$stats` variable and `$magnumId` is StockId of magnum. Example of usage: `$magnumStats = $stats[$magnumId]; echo 'Magnum kills:' . $magnumStats['TotalKills'];`.

Comment: if I use the method above with keyBy, I get an error: **Cannot use object of type stdClass as array**

Comment: @David try replacing `$magnumStats['TotalKills']` with `$magnumStats->TotalKills`.

Comment: starkky, I meant the public function method is not working, I haven't gotten to $magnumStats yet.